# Fatal error: Call to a member function set_rules()

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am getting the following error on line 17 `Fatal error: Call to a member function set_rules() on a non-object`

I have the `form_validation` library on autoload.

```
    public function login()
    {
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('userName','userName', 'required|valid_email|trim|max_length[99]|xss_clean');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('userPassword','userPassword', 'required|trim|max_length[200]|xss_clean|callback__checkUser');

            if($this->form_validation->run() === TRUE) {
            // set CLEAN data in the session.
                redirect('admin/dashboard');
            }else{

            $this->index();
        }
    }
```

**Controller**

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Login extends CI_Controller {


    public function index()
    {
        $data['companyName'] = $this->core_model->companyName();
        $data['pageTitle'] = "Administration Login";
        $this->load->view('admin/assets/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('admin/login.php', $data);
        $this->load->view('admin/assets/footer');
    }

    public function login()
    {
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('userName','userName', 'required|valid_email|trim|max_length[99]|xss_clean');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('userPassword','userPassword', 'required|trim|max_length[200]|xss_clean|callback__checkUser');


            if($this->form_validation->run() === TRUE) {
            // set CLEAN data in the session.
                redirect('admin/dashboard');
            }else{

            $this->index();
        }
    }

    function _checkUser(){ // Private function 
        extract($_POST);

        $login = $this->admin_model->check_login($userName,$userPassword,$userGroup,$userEmail,$userActive);

        if(! $login){
            $this->session->set_flashdata('login_error', TRUE); 
            $this->form_validation->set_message('_checkUser','Sorry your %s is not correct');

            return FALSE;

    }else{
        if($user->userGroup == "admin" && $user->userActive == "yes")
        {
        $this->session->set_userdata('logged_in', TRUE);
        $this->session->set_userdata('userID', $user->id);
        $this->session->set_userdata('userName',$user->userName);
        $this->session->set_userdata('firstName',$user->userFirstName);
        $this->session->set_userdata('lastName',$user->userLastName);
        $this->session->set_userdata('userEmail',$user->userEmail);
        $this->session->set_userdata('userGroup',$user->userGroup);
        $this->session->set_userdata('userActive',$user->userActive);
        }else{
        $this->session->set_flashdata('login_error', TRUE); 
        $this->form_validation->set_message('_checkUser','Sorry your %s is not correct');

        return FALSE;
    }

    }

    }
}

/* End of file login.php */
/* Location: ./application/controllers/admin/login.php */
```

Comment: Okay, but do you set $this->form_validation anywhere? It's trying to tell you that $this->form_validation is not an object.

Comment: +1 @Dan's comment, if you `var_dump($this->form_validation)` chances are it will say `NULL` or `FALSE`

Comment: @Dan Could you give me a setting example.

Comment: `$this->form_validation = new Form_Validation();` preferably done in a constructor as your class seems to depend on it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Did you forgot to write the constructor?

```
class Login extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
    }    

    ...
```

Comment: That's unnecessary overriding. If you don't define a constructor and extend a class it calls the parent's constructor my default.

Comment: I think this is what was causing the issue

Comment: @JessMcKenzie This can't be the problem, unless you were overriding the constructor before without calling the parent's constructor. If you don't override a constructor while utilizing polymorphism, the parent constructor will automatically be called.

Answer (score 3):

Try to check your model file.

I've the same error with you, and when I check it, I write in my model class

```
Class Mymodel extends CI_Controller
```

And when I change into

```
Class Mymodel extends CI_Model
```

The problem solved

Answer (score 1):

You are not loading the Form Validation library. Include

```
$this->load->library('form_validation');
```

in the method or constructor of your class. Alternatively, you can autoload it by editing **application/config/autoload.php**.

Change

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array();
```

to

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('form_validation');
```

Comment: Can you access form_validation if you require it manually? Have you tried creating an empty controller /application/controller/test.php and checking whether $this->form_validation exists from there? Can you use the other libraries that you autoload?

Answer (score 0):

`$this->form_validation->set_rules` does not exist in the class you are in. Is that a class you have made yourself? Does it extend `CI_Controller`?

I don't have a lot of experience with CI, but as said above, "It's trying to tell you that $this->form_validation is not an object" in the current class.

**Update:**

You need to load the lib:

```
$this->load->library('form_validation');
```

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#thecontroller

Comment: You need to add this: `$this->load->library('form_validation');`

Answer (score 0):

From the tutorial of CodeIgniter [Link](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html): You have to add

```
$this->load->library('form_validation');
```

to load the library.

Comment: What do you want to tell me with that? Does it not work after adding the library?

Comment: In the tutorial they also add the line `$this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));`. Did you have a look at the tutorial?

Answer (score 0):

load the form_validation libraries in the application/config/autoload.php file

Answer (score 0):

Ahh !! I come across the same problem and have tried the above solutions none of them was the case with me, instead I had to put "return false" in the first line of my callback_function. I suggest use a format like this and do test run after that, implement your code in it so you are sure that set_rule is working firne:

```
    public function checkField($str)
    {
            if ($str == 'test')
            {
                    return FALSE;
            }
            else
            {
                    return TRUE;
            }
    }
```